# Why are my answers wrong for braking distances?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I have been working on a presentation to find the braking distances at the velocities of cars obeying speed limits for a range of common speed limits.

I'm working with the equation

$$d= \frac{v^2}{2\mu g}$$

Where my problem lies is that I have been checking my work at different "Stopping Distance Calculators" that I'll list below, but the answers I got myself with the formula I was given give me answers much, much larger than the answers I got when checking my work.

Work:

Note: I am aware that velocity has a direction, but I assume nobody is driving against the flow of traffic(I hope), so I work as if they are all driving in a positive direction

I am using .5 for $\mu$ for dry roads and .25 for wet roads

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}  \textrm{mph} & \mathrm{ft/s} & \textrm{Dry(feet)} & \textrm{Wet(feet)}\\ \hline \\ 20 & 29.33 &    87.78    & 175.6\\ 25 & 36.67 &   137.2  & 274.4\\ 30 & 44 &  197.5 & 395.1\\ 35 & 51.33 &    268.9 & 537.7\\ 40 & 58.67  &    351.2   & 702.5\\ 45 & 66 &   444.5 & 889.0\\ 65 & 95.33  & 927.3  & 1855\\ 70 & 102.67  &  1076  & 2151\\ 85 & 124.67 &    1586  & 3172\end{array}$$

Calculators:

[ForensicDynamics](http://forensicdynamics.com/stopping-braking-distance-calculator)

[Random Science](http://www.random-science-tools.com/physics/stopping-distance.htm)

Comment: Forensic Dynamics results don't match this table, being more than a factor of 2 .

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: you used the value of $g$ with the wrong units

---

The coefficient of friction for rubber on asphalt is much larger than you assumed: according to [engineering toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/friction-coefficients-d_778.html) it is around 0.7

When I use that value, I get exactly the same values as your first link, ForensicDynamics, for dry asphalt at 50 mph.

Note - you have to make sure you are using the right value for $g$ - when you convert everything to feet and seconds, you need g = 32.15 ft/sec$^2$. I get the value you were getting when you use µ=0.5, and g = 9.8 - but that has units of m/s...

Note - your equation assumes zero reaction time (or perhaps it's just intended to look at the length of the skid mark). In reality people take at least 0.2 second before they start braking, which increases the stopping distance a bit more.

Comment: Ha! Nailed it. +1.